# Авторизация на сайте через python

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Как авторизоваться на сайте https://livesurf.ru/ ?

Пытался через rest client отправлять запросы с заголовками, но всегда оставался на странице авторизации, никаких ошибок и прочего не было.

Необходимо войти в личный кабинет через python, чтобы в дальнейшем иметь возможность отправлять другие запросы.

Comment: Через браузер авторизоваться и повторить запрос в requests. Смотреть на запросы браузера можно через инспектор (F12) на вкладке Сети

Comment: Скорее всего, никак. Они используют капчу в форме входа.

Comment: @gil9red а что если также нужно решать капчу? Ваш ответ поможет?

Comment: Нет, ответ @gil9red не поможет. Капча посылает каждый раз уникальный токен. Повторная отправка записанного токена не пройдёт.

Comment: @PakUula, разве что самостоятельно пройти капчу, сохранить куки и ими пользоваться в дальнейшем. Мб лучше через selenium это сделать

Comment: @gil9red то есть пройдя авторизацию ( решив капчу ) и сохранив куки в дальнейшем при отправке запроса - я сразу же попаду на сайт в личный кабинет?

Comment: @MaximChyorny, ага, но не факт, что серверу что-нибудь не понравится в будущем и куки окажутся недействительными, да и они сами по себе могут иметь короткий срок жизни (нужно в описании к кукам смотреть их срок)

Comment: @gil9red у меня получилось войти в личный кабинет через rest client отправив куки!!! Огромное спасибо вам теперь я смогу сделать свои серые делишки :) Жду от вас ответ на вопрос для подтверждения!

Comment: @gil9red а в каком именно поле можно посмотреть срок действия куки?

Comment: @MaximChyorny, эта инфа записана в сами куки (когда их сайт возвращает в заголовке ответа Set-Cookie), но можно через браузер посмотреть через инспектора (вкладка хранилище или что-то вроде такого)

Comment: Во втором поле Set-coockie написано `expires=Sat, 08-Oct-2022 12:11:48 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=livesurf.ru; secure; HttpOnly`, если перевести 31536000 секунд в дни получается 365 и на основании этого можно сказать, что куки будет жить 1 год?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сайт для защиты от ботов использовал капчу гугла

Автору помогло ручное прохождение авторизации сайта и последующее использование кук (cookies), полученных после нее

Привожу ссылку на раздел документации по использованию кук в requests: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies